# how to find td Element present or not - selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium

Html Code

```
<table class="adminlist" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr data-bind="if: RowCounts>0, attr: {StatusId: Id, DescName:Name}" statusid="2" descname="Abandoned"></tr>
<tr data-bind="if: RowCounts>0, attr: {StatusId: Id, DescName:Name}" statusid="1" descname="Active">
<td style="width: 5%;">
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { accesskey: Id }" accesskey="1">
</td>
<td class="country">
<span data-bind="text:Name">Active</span>
 (
<span data-bind="text:RowCounts">20</span>
)
</td>
</tr>
```

how can we find "td" Element present or not with the above table, based on the above first row dont have an td element but the second row its have an td element

java code

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> renewalStatus = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
        List<WebElement> activeAssetStatus = driver.findElements(By
                .xpath("//*[@id='divPatPortfolioStatusCount']/table/tbody/tr"));

        for (int i = 1; i <= activeAssetStatus.size(); i++) {
            List<WebElement> statusValue = activeAssetStatus.get(i)
                    .findElements(By.tagName("td"));

            if (statusValue.size() > 0) {
                WebElement al = driver
                        .findElement(By
                                .xpath("//*[@id='divPatPortfolioStatusCount']/table/tbody/tr["
                                        + i + "]/td[2]"));

                String mainText = al.getText();
                final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\s*\\((.*?)\\)");
                final Matcher m = p.matcher(mainText);
                m.find();
                String name = m.group(1);
                String count = m.group(2);
                renewalStatus.put(name, Integer.parseInt(count));
            }
        }
}
```

for the above code not able to collect and store the td values in hash table
its produce "NoSuchElementException"
because inside the if condition i value 1 so its produce this exception, how can i collect corresponding row with td value

Answer (score 0):

```
List <WebElement> allTrElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='adminlist']/tbody/tr"));

for(int i= 0;i<allTrElements.size();i++){
   List<WebElement> allTdElements = allTrElements.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
   if(allTdElements.size() > 0 ){
      // if confirms <tr> contains <td>
   }
}
```

Comment: @shekhar Please find my java code inside the loop that i values become 1

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver mainDriver = new ChromeDriver();

//get the table element
WebElement eleTable = mainDriver.findElement(By.tagName("table");

//get the list of row elements of table
List<WebElement>tableRowList = eleTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(int i = 0 ; i < tableRowList.size(); i++) {
    //take individual rows
    WebElement rowElement = tableRowList.get(i);

    //get the list of td elements
    List<WebElement> dataElement = rowElement.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    if(dataElement.size() > 0) {
        //if size > 0, there are td elements in it.
    }
}
```

​

Comment: Can you please tell me what you want to fetch from td element?

Comment: :span value inside that td (Active, 20), scrape all rows in that table find and collect all the td values

Comment: When you are checking if (statusValue.size() > 0), instead of using xpath to determine 2nd td element. try iterating the obtained td list, i.e, statusValue. So in that statusValue.get(1) will give you 2nd td element.

Comment: Thanks for your help , please find the for loop its working correctly, but its consume more time to complete the loop for (int i = 1; i <= activeAssetStatus.size(); i++) {
   List<WebElement> df = driver
     .findElement(
       By.xpath("//*[@id='divPatPortfolioStatusCount']/table/tbody/tr["
         + i + "]")).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
   if (df.size() > 0) {
    WebElement al = driver
      .findElement(By
        .xpath("//*[@id='divPatPortfolioStatusCount']/table/tbody/tr["
          + i + "]/td[2]"));    
  }